# How to add a gif animation in a wpf page of class library project?

Tags: c#, wpf, class-library, revit-api, revit

I am new to creating revit addins and using class library projects. Currently, I am creating an addin using a class library project and the first screen is a login screen(using wpf for this) and I want to add a gif animation to that wpf page. I have searched online and found some solutions (wpfanimatedgif nuget package, mediaelement) but the gif won't play inside revit. So I tried these solutions in a WPF project instead of class library project. And they worked. Can someone please help me? Is there another nuget package available?
Thanks

**EDIT:-**
Inside 
[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC33F.jpg)
, it does shows the thumbnail of the GIF when I use the media element.

But inside 
[Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuIF6.jpg)
, even the thumbnail for the GIF is not visible

In the Xaml:

```
<MediaElement Name="My_GIF" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" Source="Images\planBIMGIF.gif"/>
```

In the code behind:-

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            My_GIF.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            My_GIF.Play();
            //MessageBox.Show("Playing GIF");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just use an image in WPF instead of a media element because with a media element my animations keep stopping before finishing the animation. So now I just feed it to the image frame by frame. You also have more control over it like this.

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

Code-behind (in a function that gets called after InitializeComponent):

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("Images\planBIMGIF.gif", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
GifBitmapDecoder decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(myUri,       
BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource;
int frameCount = decoder.Frames.Count;

Thread th = new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < frameCount - 1; i++)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate ()
        {
            bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[i];
            image.Source = bitmapSource;
        }));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
});
th.Start();
```

This plays the gif once and stops at the frame before the last one (my gifs had a blank frame at the end). If you want it to repeat, you can put the 'for' loop in a while loop or some other loop of your preference.
You can adjust the speed by setting the `Thread.Sleep(50)` time to something else.

Also, be sure to set your image as "resource" in its properties, and you might have to reference it like this in the Uri: `"pack://application:,,,/<ProjectName>;component/Images/planBIMGIF.gif"` with `<ProjectName>` being the name of your project in VS.